# Issue with nested "ifs" VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, compilation

I'm getting a compiled error for nested ifs in VBA See the code below:

```
Function checkPrefix(ByVal term As String) As String
Dim prefixarrU, prefixarrL, compareValue

compareValue = (StrComp(term, UCase(term), vbBinaryCompare))

prefixarrU = Array("U", "M", "L")
prefixarrL = Array("e", "m", "l")

If compareValue = 0 Then
    'char is uppercase
    For x = LBound(prefixarrU) To UBound(prefixarrU)
        If (prefixarrU(x) = term And term = "U") Then
            checkPrefix = "upper "
        ElseIf (prefixarrU(x) = term And term = "M") Then
            checkPrefix = "middle "
        ElseIf (prefixarrU(x) = term And term = "L") Then
            checkPrefix = "lower "
        Else
            checkPrefix = ""
        End If
ElseIf compareValue <> 0 Then
    'char is lowercase
    For x = LBound(prefixarrL) To UBound(prefixarrL)
        If prefixarrL(x) = term And term = "e" Then
            checkPrefix = "early "
        ElseIf prefixarrL(x) = term And term = "m" Then
            checkPrefix = "medial "
        ElseIf prefixarrL(x) = term And term = "L" Then
            checkPrefix = "late "
        Else
            checkPrefix = ""
        End If
Else
    'Error
End If

End Function
```

- Note sure why I get the error, I did end all the if statements with end if.
  Some sort of explanation.

Comment: You have no `next` to go with the `for` both loops will need it

Comment: Ah, nevermind, I forgot the "next x" after each for loop, would of been nice if the compiler told me that rather than the If error

Comment: Using [VBA Rubberduck](https://rubberduckvba.com/)'s or[MZTools](https://www.mztools.com/)'s code formatters warn of miss matched code blocks such as:  loops, if statements, select statements, subs an functions.

Answer (score 3):

```vb
Function checkPrefix(ByVal term As String) As String

    Dim d As Object: Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    d.Add "U", "upper"
    d.Add "M", "middle"
    d.Add "L", "lower"
    d.Add "e", "early"
    d.Add "m", "medial"
    d.Add "l", "late"
    checkPrefix = d(term)

End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take advantage of the "Select Case" statement

```
Function CheckPrefix(ByVal term As String) As String

    Select Case Left$(termi, 1)
        Case "U"
            CheckPrefix = "upper "
        Case "M"
            CheckPrefix = "middle "
        Case "L"
            CheckPrefix = "lower "
        Case "e"
            CheckPrefix = "early "
        Case "m"
            CheckPrefix = "medial "
        Case "l"
            CheckPrefix = "late "
        Case Else
            CheckPrefix = vbNullString
    End Select

End Function
```